# Selling my ps3; is there a way to leave the digital purchases on the console but without use my PSN account?

Tags: ps3, psn

I was planning to dismiss my ps3; although I have about 10 games that are digital only; that I did purchase on the PSN store.

Since they are tied to my account, this means that I cannot leave the games on the console with my PSN account logged in for security reasons.

On my old Xbox I could remove my account and create a fresh empty account, and the games would continue to work; but it does not seem to be the case with PS3.

Is there a way for me to leave the ps3 games on the console but remove my account info; so they can play the games and I am safe knowing that nobody will use my account (in case I may want to use it again in the future with PS5 for example, if they will ever enable retro-compatibility. Thanks

Comment: I highly recommend you take the secure option and just wipe the hard drive and set it back to factory settings (reinstall the PS3 OS).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for me to leave the ps3 games on the console but remove my account info

No.